# Create TypeScript generic type that extends interface with only string keys

Tags: typescript

I want to make a generic class that requires a template parameter that is an interface with only string keys.

I thought I could do something like

```ts
class MyClass<T extends Record<string, object>> {
    sendEventData<TKey extends keyof T>(event: TKey, data: T[TKey]) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

However, if I instantiate it like

```ts
interface MyEvents {
    someEvent: { foo: string }
}

const instanace = new MyClass<MyEvents>();
```

I get a compilation error:

```
Type 'MyEvents' does not satisfy the constraint 'Record<string, object>'.
  Index signature is missing in type 'MyEvents'.
```

If I remove `extends Record<string, object` entirely, it compiles fine, but it doesn't restrict it to a map of string => object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Record<string, >` implies that it accepts any key, which you don't want.

Instead, write `T extends Record<string&keyof T, object>` to restrict it to only keys that exist on the type, and that are also strings.

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcUA8AVaBTAHgFywDsATGAJS2AHsAnY1CPGgS0IHMAyAay3ioDNo6ADTQqAIwBWlPAD5Z0AN4AoaGugQixAKIA3IngAiYPGAwBpXtnxaYPPoPSyAFFn2E8ALiGX4o4iZg3ugA2ui+ALoAlEqq6vEA9AnQAHRpcWoAvsrZrAQ0-GDAWHDwegYwKvEQVAC2WOUe3orQ-FRU3ows7NDZ2crUhIzQrIxghEUlALzQhFgA7qXIkBCoCI14EC5RANzKQA)

Comment: That doesn't work, keyof T would not be restricted to string. 

sendEventData<TKey extends keyof T>(event: TKey, data: T[TKey]) {
      event.toLowerCase() // error, event is type string | number | symbol
}